# Is there any package in npm which does Base64 encoding and decoding as defined by RFC 2045?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a base-64 encoded string which I need to decode in node.js which is defined by RFC 2045.

Comment: Suggest googling "base64 npm".

Comment: `Buffer.from(string, 'base64')`

Answer (score 0):

Searching `npm` there are:

- [2573 results for ‘base64’](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=base64)

None of them work for you?

Comment: not just for base64 but decoding complied with rfc 2057 is what I require.

Comment: @saurabh You mean RFC 2045, right? What parts of this RFC are those modules not compliant with?